# JS and regex: replace all img by their [src]?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

My goal is to replace all  tags by [src] only

```
hello <img class="gif" src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/zU4MLqeDvGA0M/100.gif" title="1"> hello      
world <img class="gif" src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/zU4MLqeDvGA0M/100.gif" title="2"> hello2
```

by

```
[https://media2.giphy.com/media/zU4MLqeDvGA0M/100.gif] [https://media2.giphy.com/media/zU4MLqeDvGA0M/100.gif]
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZPOCCe/1

(My regex works fine ONLY where there is a line between the 2 images. It looks like it is greedy)

Any idea ?

Comment: Besides setting non greedy, in some cases you can also add a safeguard by replacing `.*` with one or multiple non matchers  `[^"]*`. You can also use backreferences to match with like in: https://regex101.com/r/4RGCjo/1 But it's actually pretty hard, because you can have a valid src attribute without quotes and you might need something like lookaheads.

Comment: Instead of writing regex yourself, can't you use an actual html parser? Like the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.*?` (add a question mark after) to make the regex lazy instead of greedy (just `.*`).